# How to destroy .rangeinput object in jquery-tools after page rendered

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

How to destroy .rangeinput slider after page rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the range in the DIV

```
<div id="myRange">
 <input type="range" name="test" min="100" max="300" value="150" />  
</div>

<br /><br/><br />
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
```

And then in the script remove the DIV upon some event eg button click

```
$(":range").rangeinput();
$("#remove").on('click',function(){$("#myRange").remove();});
```